# Flutter: Get information from scanned barcode number and using php

Tags: php, flutter

I am quite new to Flutter, and I am currently working on an application that needs barcode reading. So I used the barcode_scan library, and I am now able to get the barcode number from a scanned barcode.I had try using php to extract information in flutter,but it still cannot extract information and just get the barcode number.

To be clear, I am not asking how to scan a barcode / get the barcode number.

My question is: how can I get more information about a product from its barcode number in Flutter (e.g. product name)? Can I do this from the barcode_scan library and using php or will I need something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following things to retrieve product information.

1. I assume you have one product table in DB, add one barcode field in the product table where you can set the barcode of every product.
2. Made one API that fetches the product details from the Barcode number.
3. Call that API on the success of the barcode scan, and you will get the product info.

Comment: 1.yes i have a table in database, may i ask how to call information using php?
2.what API ? i not understands it